# Import workbook using a predetermined directory and the name found in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, import, getopenfilename

I currently import sheets of data into excel that I am exporting from CAD. This includes summaries, counts and other data. I would like to add to the code so that it will import a file from a predetermined directory `C:\Jobs\packlist` and using a number inside a cell `='PL CALC'!B1` (this will determine the file name). The idea being to remove the open dialog box and increase automation.

This is what I have found that works so far. It opens a selected file and copies it into the workbook after sheet 18.

```
'import excel data sheet

Sub import()

Dim fName As String, wb As Workbook

'where to look for the framecad excel file

ChDrive "C:"
ChDir "C:\Jobs\packlist"

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fName)
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
            Sheets.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(18)
            Exit For
            Next
    wb.Close False      
    Worksheets("PL CALC").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question? You didn't ask one (see [ask]). Also incude what problems you faced, and what did not work. Or did you just mean to replace the open dialog with `fName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PL CAC").Range("B1").Value`?

Comment: Is there only one sheet in the workbook where from your code tries copying? If not, `Exit For` will allow only the first sheet copying. Then, you can replace all above the loop with: `fName = "C:\Jobs\packlist\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PL CAC").Range("B1").Value`.

Comment: Is `Sheets(18)` the last sheet in your workbook?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yup sorry, the question is how can I amend my code to do what is required.

Comment: @FaneDuru there are potentially unlimited sheets in the cad exported workbook.

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes - sheet 18 is currently the last page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Import Sheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportSheets()
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Import Sheets"

    Const sFolderPath As String = "C:\Jobs\packlist\"
    Const sfnAddress As String = "B1"
    Const sFileExtensionPattern As String = ".xls*"
    
    Const dwsName As String = "PL CALC"
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dwsName)
    
    Dim sFilePattern As String: sFilePattern = sFolderPath & "*" _
        & dws.Range(sfnAddress).Value & sFileExtensionPattern
    
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sFilePattern)
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No file found..." & vbLf & "'" & sFilePattern & "'", _
            vbCritical, ProcTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFolderPath & sFileName)
        
    Dim sh As Object
        
    For Each sh In swb.Sheets
        sh.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
    Next sh
    
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    dws.Activate
    'dwb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Sheets imported.", vbInformation, ProcTitle
    
End Sub
```